# Keyboard + Trackpad not working in MacOS but work in Ubuntu

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, usb, trackpad

My 2015 13" Macbook Pro's keyboard and trackpad no longer work and I've already replaced the connector flex cable twice. That worked for a few weeks but after the third replacement they keyboard and trackpad no longer work (I assume the new flex cable works).

Interestingly, the keyboard and mouse work just fine when I boot from an Ubuntu live USB stick. In a youtube video by Louis Rossmann I can no longer find he mentions this may be due to the Macbook being connected to the keyboard and trackpad via USB by default. Something in the connection/USB controller may be damaged and Ubuntu can fallback to SPI to connect to the keyboard and trackpad whereas MacOS lacks drivers for this.

My question is whether a) how I can test this hypothesis and whether there may be a driver for MacOS that can connect to the keyboard via SPI and b) whether I can otherwise avoid replacing the entire keyboard/trackpad/battery ensemble.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I have the same problem. MBA 2015. Keyboard, trackpad stopped working after updating to Big Sur. Both work on an Ubuntu Live USB. Reinstalled Big Sur and Catalina couple of time but in vain.