# MacBook pro's trackpad and keyboard works in diagnosis mode only but nowhere else

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad, macos

I have MacBook Pro early 2015 model and using macOS Big Sur. My trackpad and keyboard suddenly stopped working after rebooting. Strangely, when I enter into diagnosis mode by holding down the 'D' key, the trackpad and keyboard are totally workable. I can move around the mouse pointer using trackpad there as well as toggle caps lock light using a button.

Comment: You should probably mention which operating system you are running. Additionally you may want to see if it works in Safe Mode, reset the SMC/NVRAM, and see if it works with USB mouse/keyboard. If it works with USB mouse/keyboards, it’s possible something has gone wrong with the top case and/or IO board. If you replace the top case, the cost should be around the cost of replacing battery (as the battery is glued to the top case), so you’ll get a new keyboard/trackpad and a new battery. If it’s the IO board, that’s about $100-200, unless these are directly connected to the logic board? Not sure

Comment: @AVelj It didn't work in Safe Mode. I tried resetting NVRAM, PRAM, and SMC but no luck there. However, I am not convinced that it is a hardware issue because the keyboard and trackpad work fine in diagnostic mode.

Comment: Similar question https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/368659/keyboard-trackpad-not-working-in-macos-but-work-in-ubuntu